# PHP mktime giving dates 12 off

Tags: php, mktime

I am writing a function to convert an internal date format into a timestamp value. However, when I print the date out in YYYY-MM-DD HH format the date is 12 hours off.

The code below gives me the wrong date and time. I am expecting 2011-03-25 13 but instead I am getting 2011-03-25 01.

```
 date_default_timezone_set("Europe/London");
 $epoch = mktime(13,0,0,3,25,2011);
 echo date('Y-m-d h', $epoch);
```

When I use the following code I expect 2001-02-01 01 and get what I expected.

```
 date_default_timezone_set("Europe/London");
 $epoch = mktime(1,0,0,2,1,2011);
 echo date('Y-m-d h', $epoch);
```

It seems that the 12 hour offset starts on March 25th in the 13th hour.

Any idea why this happens and how do I keep it from happening? Does this have to do with the different day light savings dates? The server timezone is set to "America/Los_Angeles".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works, you're just using the wrong format code, take `H` (24 hour format) instead of `h` (12 hour format):

```
date_default_timezone_set("Europe/London");
$epoch = mktime(13,0,0,3,25,2011);
echo date('Y-m-d H', $epoch);
```

Read the [PHP Manual](http://php.net/date), it explains each code in detail.

Comment: Oh wow, moment of stupidity right now. I can't believe I over looked that. Ug.

Comment: The sad thing is that I fixed a similar mistake for some one recently. One of those days.